# How to Create SOQL for a visualforce Search Page in below format

Tags: visualforce, soql

HI i want to create a search page in below format. Kindly help me in writing the soql query in controller when user enters the Values for Min and Max fields for Square Footage.

[image: `Visual force Search page]
    Below is the Visual force page code.

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="Condosearchcontroller"     showHeader="true"> 
<style type="text/css">
        body {background: #F3F3EC; padding-top: 5px}
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Find Units" action="{!search}"/>  
               <apex:commandButton value="Reset" action="{!Clear}"/>
               <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
               </apex:pageBlockButtons>
               <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" collapsible="false">
                     <apex:inputText value="{!beds}"  label="Beds" />
                     <apex:inputText value="{!SFminimum}"  label="Min" />
                     <apex:inputText value="{!SFmaximum}"  label="Max"/>
                     </apex:pageBlockSection>
           <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Cond}" var="a" id="table">  
         <apex:column >  
          <apex:outputlink value="https://cs19.salesforce.com/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}       </apex:outputlink>  
</apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Beds__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Square_Footage__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Initial_List_Price__c}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>


public with sharing class Condosearchcontroller { 
   public Condosearchcontroller() {
}
public list <Condo__c> Cond {get;set;}  
    public string beds {get;set;} 
    public string squarefootage {get;set;}
    public string SFminimum {get;set;}
    public string SFmaximum {get;set;}
    public string InitialListPrice {get;set;} 
    public string ILPminimum {get;set;}
    public string ILPmaximum {get;set;}
    public Condosearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
   }  
public void Search(){
string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c from Condo__c where name!=NULL';
         if (!beds.equals('')) 
              searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'';
          if(!SFminimum.equals('') && SFmaximum.equals(''))
              searchquery+= ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+'';
      Cond= Database.query(searchquery);
          }
public void clear(){  
   Cond.clear();  
   }  
 }
```

HI all thank you for your replies. Itried modifying the code in the below format .but still not able to retrieve correct data. all i need is how to Pass the integer values in max amd min fields in the page to soql query in the controller.

```
public with sharing class Condosearchcontroller { 
   public Condosearchcontroller() {

    }

    public list <Condo__c> Cond {get;set;}  
    public string beds {get;set;} 
    public string squarefootage {get;set;}
    public string SFminimum {get;set;}
    public string SFmaximum {get;set;}
    public string InitialListPrice {get;set;} 

public Condosearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
   }  

   public void search(){
       Integer SFmin = Integer.valueof(SFminimum);
       Integer SFmax = Integer.Valueof(SFmaximum);

    string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c from Condo__c where name!=NULL';
         if (!beds.equals('')) 
              searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'and Square_Footage__c >= :SFmin and Square_Footage__c <= :SFmax ';

              Cond= Database.query(searchquery);

}

public void clear(){  
   Cond.clear();  
   }  
 }
```

HI Keith c, i have made the changes given by you.now i have a different problem. when i execute the below apex search method. when i enter beds it is giving me data and when i enter SFminimum and SFmaximum it is giving me data. but when i enter both Beds,SFminimum and SFmaximum.it is not returning the correct data. kindly help me correcting the code.

```
public Condosearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
   }  

   public void search(){

       Integer SFmin = Integer.valueof(SFminimum);
       Integer SFmax = Integer.Valueof(SFmaximum);
       Integer ILPmin = Integer.valueof(ILPminimum);
       Integer ILPmax = Integer.valueof(ILPmaximum);

     string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c,Status__c from Condo__c where name!=null and Status__c in (\'Available\',\'Unsold\') ';

           if (!beds.equals('')) {
              searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'';
              }
           else if (SFminimum != null && SFmaximum != null) {

               searchquery+= ' and Square_Footage__c >= :SFmin and Square_Footage__c <= :SFmax ';
           }

           else if ((!beds.equals('')) && (SFminimum != null && SFmaximum != null))

               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= :SFmin and Square_Footage__c <= :SFmax ';

         Cond= Database.query(searchquery);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach will work whether values are entered or not: if no value is entered then the biggest possible number (assuming integers here) is used:

```
public CustomObject__c getCond() {

    Integer min = SFminimum != null ? Integer.valueOf(SFminimum) : -2147483648;
    Integer max = SFmaximum != null ? Integer.valueOf(SFmaximum) : 2147483647;

    return [
            select Id, Name, Beds__c, Square_Footage__c, Initial_List_Price__c
            from Cond__c
            where Square_Footage__c >= :min
            and Square_Footage__c <= :max
            order by Name
            ];
}
```

**PS**

This is how I would write a version that uses dyamic SOQL:

```
public void Search(){
    String soql = ''
            + ' select name, Beds__c, Square_Footage__c, Initial_List_Price__c'
            + ' from Condo__c'
            + ' where name != null'
            ;
    if (!String.isEmpty(beds)) soql += ' and Beds__c = :beds';
    if (!String.isEmpty(SFminimum)) soql += ' and Square_Footage__c >= :SFminimum';
    if (!String.isEmpty(SFmaximum)) soql += ' and Square_Footage__c <= :SFmaximum';
    Cond = Database.query(soql);
}
```

**PPS**

A simple way to validate that the text entered is a number change the field type to Integer:

```
public Integer SFminimum {get;set;}
public Integer SFmaximum {get;set;}
```

and you will automatically get a message like this when the user's input is not valid (providing you have an `apex:pageMessages` tag in your page).

> Value 'abc' cannot be converted from Text to Number

Note that no input will be mapped to the integer 0.

Comment: hI Keith c, Thanks for your reply.  I have added the Visual force Page code and apex controller. kindly let me know where to do the changes in the code

Comment: @chaitanya Edit your post, select the code and then click the {} button and the save. Otherwise the formatting is terrible.

Comment: @chaitanya Your code looks good to me - its pretty common to use dynamic SOQL as you are doing. Is there a problem with it? Note that you should wrap the strings in String.escapeSingleQuotes or use the bind variable syntax to avoid the risk of SOQL injection attaches (Google that if you haven't heard about it before).

Comment: i have made some changes to controller.still not able to get the correct data.

Comment: @chaitanya I've just added a PS with how I would do it using dynamic SOQL. But I'm not sure what problem you are hitting so the code may not help.

Comment: HI keith c, i got the solution now every thing is working fine.but i need one more help. in the visual force page how make the inputfields accept only integer values.

Comment: @chaitanya See PPS.

Comment: HI Keith c, i have made the changes given by you.now i have a different problem. when i execute the below apex search method. when i enter beds it is giving me data and when i enter SFminimum and SFmaximum it is giving me data. but when i enter both Beds,SFminimum and SFmaximum.it is not returning the correct data. kindly help me correcting the code.

Comment: @chaitanya The logic is wrong in the edited question in that whenever the bed value isn't an empty string the min and max are ignored. The correct logic is shown in the PS answer: `if`s not `else if``s.

Comment: when i try to enter the code in PS and execute it. i am getting a below error message "System.QueryException: Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Decimal
Error is in expression '{!search}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page condossearchpage: Class.Condosearchcontroller.Search: line 39, column 1

Comment: @chaitanya You'll have to use local variables of the right type as in the first answer.

Comment: @Hi Keith c, can you help me in writing a Javascript method. to update a Field value in Leads object form the list of records displayed in the visualforce page.for example in the Vf page i want to display a link "Select" when user clicks on "select" the unit name of  record should be updated to Unit Field in Leads.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to achieve that is having a custom apex controller, where you have a method which returns your related opportunity list based on your min max operators. A basic implementation should look something like:

```
public class customOpportunityController {


public customOpportunityController(){   
}


public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities(Interger  minValue, Integer maxValue){

    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>([Select id,name from Opportunity where SF__c>: minValue and SF__c <: maxValue])      
    return  opps;
}

}
```

Then you have to make sure your VisualForce Page has the controller set to your custom one such as.

```
<apex:page Controller="customOpportunityController"  extensions="Condosearchcontroller"     showHeader="true">
```

and then call the methods from your vf page with the min and max values you are setting.

This should give you a good starting point of what you should be doing. Not using a standard controller anymore you would also need to make sure that you implement the methods you are already using for displaying the opportunities which are being provided by the standardController. You can find here more details about custom controllers and how to implement them: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

Comment: can you help me in writing a Javascript method. to update a Field value in Leads object form the list of records displayed in the visualforce page.for example in the Vf page i want to display a link "Select" when user clicks on "select" the unit name of record should be updated to Unit Field in Leads.